# Exporting .obj to THREE.js models using blender / threejs.org editor

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm having consistent issues when trying to convert an .obj file to js format that THREE.js can read.

I go to http://threejs.org/editor and import a .obj model and then click file and then "Export Geometry" but nothing happens when it's a file that I imported.
If i create a simple cube in the editor it will export fine.

I downloaded the blender threejs addon.
Same for that, when I import a .obj file to blender and then export it gives me an error that points to the THREE.js addon.

For every model I've imported it does not export.

How come some models can export geometries properly and others fail?

I've also tried using some online editors that support threejs but they shade out the THREEJS Export Geometry for my models and only allow me to export threejs scene which with my testing does not work propely.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Edit: I've also tried the Python converter and errors also occur. I used both Python 3x and 2x.

Comment: I've utilized all these methods with success. Could we see examples of the models your failing on? My first suspect might be are they triangulated or quads?

Comment: @Darryl_Lehmann Here is a model I tried and it did not work: http://tf3dm.com/3d-model/portal-turret-70087.html    I upload the .obj from that download to the threejs online editor and it doesn't allow me to export geometry. When I click the button it does nothing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: glad it worked out, I do believe you can mark your own question correct below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved with the threejs.org/editor

Turns out I needed to select the model in the scene first and then click export geometry.

Stupid mistakes can be a pain sometimes!

Comment: It's not your fault. The software should avoid stupid mistakes like this. I've added some alerts so this doesn't happen again :)

Comment: @mrdoob Thanks a lot mrdoob! Your work is VERY much appreciated!

Comment: @mrdoob Hey, I'm now trying to import a model i converted into threejs and got stuck here. It imports the model and materials but not the textures. I wrote up a whole post on it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122071/three-js-imported-model-doesnt-apply-face-textures   If you got a free minute to check that out, that'd be awesome! Thanks!